# turtlebot_apps compilation error

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup/Source) to setup the workstation for using the turtlebot.
When i compile the turtlebot_apps as in the final step of the tutorial, i get the below error.

```
mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f smc_6_0_1.tgz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file smc_6_0_1.tgz.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/smc_6_0_1.tgz build/smc_6_0_1.tgz `awk {'print $1'} smc_6_0_1.tgz.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/smc_6_0_1.tgz to build/smc_6_0_1.tgz...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 56, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main
      urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 91, in urlretrieve
      return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 237, in retrieve
      fp = self.open(url, data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
      return getattr(self, name)(url)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 435, in open_https
      h.endheaders(data)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
      self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1158, in connect
      self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 344, in wrap_socket
      ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 121, in __init__
      self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 283, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Can someone let me know the way to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12742/turtlebot_apps-compilation-error/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like either the server at code.ros.org was down, or there's some sort of SSL problem with either the server or the SSL libraries on your machine.

If it's a server problem, trying again later may work. You may also be able to short-circuit the problem by doing the download manually, and moving the file into the appropriate directory.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-24**:
I assume you're trying to build a specific package; that archive should end up in the build directory inside that package.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-24**:
Ya i din get that appropriate directory to which i have to put this .tgz file :(